# Want to boot Ubuntu from integrated SD card reader

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, sd-card

The title pretty much says it all, but I will give a little more detail.

I have an Asus Transformer 3 Pro which is currently setup with Windows 10 & Android-X86 installed on the SSD. If possible I would like to also boot Ubuntu from an SD card. I have had a Google about and not really found a definitive answer. As of now the installed version of GRUB2 is the one that ships with Android-X86 but I'm not fussed by it being overwritten by either a newer or older version to suit the task.

I tried installing to the SD in the vein hope it might just work and although GRUB will see and create an entry for it, it wont boot. I was thinking that maybe installing the boot partition to the SSD and everything else to the SD card might help, but I'm really just clutching at possibilities.

The installed SSD isn't large enough to hold all three OS's with associated data and apps.

Any help or links would be most welcome, cheers in advance.

Comment: Have you tried or yet to start? When you are on something else, sd card is seen?

Comment: I have tried, but only in as far as installing to the SD card and seeing how GRUB deals with it by default. The entry is there pointing to the correct device but it doesn't boot.

Comment: While installing. Device for bootloader which one have you selected? SSD or SD card?

Comment: If your BIOS/UEFI settings don't show the SD card reader, go with your other idea of updating the grub on the SSD to boot the SD with a root installed.

Comment: Hi CelticBhoy, you might add an answer and accept it or delete your question. Adding solved to the title is not helpful for anyone.

Comment: I thought I had added the solution but looking now it seems not to have saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody is struggling with the same issue I managed to solve my problem. By installing /boot onto a partition on my SSD & the everything else onto the SD card the install is both found by GRUB and boots as it should.